# Easiest way to get ID of record that was just posted

Tags: mysql, select, insert

When doing a MySQL insert with PHP what is the easiest way to get the ID of the record that was just added?

For example, lets's say you are posting a message board type post where you have user_id, post_subject, timestamp etc in the user_posts table and then you have the text of the post in the user_post_threads table.

I need to grab the ID of the new record from the user_posts table so that I can add it to the connected text post in the user_post_threads table.

My solution in the past has been to do a new query on the timestamp and user_id to get the record ID before posting the data to the user_post_threads table.  But I hate doing it that way because it seems like I'm doing an unnecessary query on my database.

I would like to improve my method so tips would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, today I am doing this in WordPress and I know WordPress often has these little hooks that you can use to get stuff like this.  But it doesn't have to be a WordPress solution as most of the time I am not doing this in WordPress.

Comment: can you say wordpress a few more times in that sentence? (:

Answer (score 3):

Super simple! If you're just using vanilla SQL

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

[More about LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

---

Sounds like your'e using PHP, which also has a native function for this.

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

[More about mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Works great :)  Wow, how did I overlook that one??

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow, Bill! If this answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information by calling the `insert_id` method equivalent in whichever mysql library you are using in php.

[`mysql_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id%5D)

[`mysqli::insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) ([`mysqli_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id))

[`PDO::lastInsertId`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

there's probably a few others..but you get the idea.